# Can't pass object prop to vue 3 web component

Tags: json, vuejs3, web-component, vue-props

I am trying to pass an object prop to a vue3 web component.

My web component:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { type Ref, ref, type PropType } from "vue";

export default {
  props: {
    text: String,
    count: {
      default: 0,
      type: Number
    },
    extraSettings: Object as PropType<{ name: String }>
  },
  setup(props, context) {
    let count: Ref<number> = ref(props.count);

    const increaseCount = () => {
      count.value++;
    };

    // expose to template and other options API hooks
    return {
      count,
      text: props.text,
      increaseCount
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.count);
    console.log(this.extraSettings);
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="increaseCount()">{{ text }} num: {{ count }}</button>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

`<my-label text="test" count="5" .extra-settings="{ name: 'john' }"></my-label>`

Main.ts

```
import { defineCustomElement } from "vue";

import MyLabel from "./components/MyLabel.ce.vue";

customElements.define("my-label", defineCustomElement(MyLabel));
```

The text parameter is passed correctly and the number parameter is also being parsed correctly.

But the object parameter is undefined

I followed the [official documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#using-custom-elements-in-vue) and tried:

- Adding a "." before the props name: extraSettings is undefined
- Adding a ":" before and ".prop" after prop name: extra-settings is undefined
- Writing only extra-settings: Prop is a string

UPDATE: settings a property on the element works but it's obviously messy:

```
<my-label
  text="{{ section.settings.text }}"
  :count="{{ section.settings.initialNumber }}"
></my-label>

<script>
  document.querySelector('my-label').extraSettings = {
    content: 'john',
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try change

```js
<my-label text="test" count="5" .extra-settings="{ name: 'john' }"></my-label>
```

to

```js
<my-label text="test" count="5" :extra-settings="{ name: 'john' }"></my-label>
```

Comment: No it doesn't work, still undefined

Comment: did you put your code into the <template></template>, i run your code in my project and it works

Comment: Why do you mean? I am creating a custom element component library. I compile it using to a .js file using vite and I then import that file to my website. Can you maybe provide a codepen, github or zip file of a working example?

Comment: https://github.com/shidaping/vue3test